# Select drop down creation and dispaly some related text based on JSon data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to implement a Bootstrap drop-down from JSon data ,which I am getting from a REST call.
So i want to display **roomTypeName**  as the drop-down options .
Based on selection of this drop-down I want to show the **price** associated with it.Below is the JSon data.

```
{
    "packageRoomTypeWithPriceList": [
        {
            "roomTypeId": 13,
            "roomTypeName": "General",
            "packagePriceVOList": [
                {
                    "packagePriceId": 48,
                    "price": "3000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "roomTypeId": 14,
            "roomTypeName": "Sharing",
            "packagePriceVOList": [
                {
                    "packagePriceId": 49,
                    "price": "3750"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "roomTypeId": 15,
            "roomTypeName": "Private",
            "packagePriceVOList": [
                {
                    "packagePriceId": 50,
                    "price": "4500"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

HTML template code which I am going to use is : 
`

```
<td>
<h3 >25,0000</h3>
<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
<button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">Private Cabin <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
<li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Shared Cabin</a></li>
<li role="menuitem"><a href="#">General Cabin</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
```

`

Suggest how I can create the drop-down form the values and based on its selection I can change the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a good starting point:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/fp68szk8/1/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="dummy">
     <h3>25,0000</h3>

    <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
        <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">Private Cabin <span class="caret"></span>

        </button>
        {{thePrice}}
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
            <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="room in rooms.packageRoomTypeWithPriceList">
                <a href="" ng-click="updatePrice(room.packagePriceVOList[0].packagePriceId)">{{room.roomTypeName}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.updatePrice = function (price) {
        $scope.thePrice = price;
    };
    $scope.rooms = {
        "packageRoomTypeWithPriceList": [{
            "roomTypeId": 13,
                "roomTypeName": "General",
                "packagePriceVOList": [{
                "packagePriceId": 48,
                    "price": "3000"
            }]
        }, {
            "roomTypeId": 14,
                "roomTypeName": "Sharing",
                "packagePriceVOList": [{
                "packagePriceId": 49,
                    "price": "3750"
            }]
        }, {
            "roomTypeId": 15,
                "roomTypeName": "Private",
                "packagePriceVOList": [{
                "packagePriceId": 50,
                    "price": "4500"
            }]
        }]
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks Michelem for your help.